# Selecting names from table

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, inner-join, where-clause

I need to list names of professor and courses that teach by professor from the list of tables schemas

PROFESSOR : ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID, , SALARY

DEPARTMENT : ID , NAME

COURSE: ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID, CREDITS

SCHEDULE: PROFESSOR_ID, COURSE_ID, SEMESTER, YEAR

The output should be

```
Brandon Matthews Clinical Biochemistry 
Brandon Matthews Clinical Neuroscience
Daniel Hicks Clinical Biochemistry 
Emily Lee Clinical Biochemistry
Emily Lee clinical Neuroscience
Emily Lee Earth Science
Theresa Peterson Earth Science
Theresa Peterson Geography
Theresa Peterson Materials Science and Metallurgy 
Theresa Peterson Pure Mathematics and Mathematical Statistics
```

The code that I tried

```
SELECT
    p.NAME,
    c.NAME 
FROM COURSE c, SCHEDULE s, PROFESSOR p 
WHERE p.ID = s.PROFESSOR_ID AND s.COURSE_ID = c.ID 
ORDER BY  p.NAME;
```

This is not printing the correct output.

Comment: What is _Clinical_, _Earth_, _Geography_... Aren't these the department names? If so, you are not fetching them in your query.

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard joins! Then it is easy to add more tables.

This is you current code:

```
select p.name, c.name 
from course c, schedule s, professor p 
where p.id = s.professor_id and s.course_id = c.id 
order by  p.name
```

This translates as:

```
select p.name as professor_name, c.name as course_name
from schedule s 
inner join course    c on c.id = s.course_id
inner join professor p on p.id = s.professor_id 
order by p.name
```

Note that I also aliased the columns in the resultset, to avoid the ambiguity caused by identical names.

From there on, you can add more tables if needed (`department` comes to mind), or implement some filtering on the `where` clause (maybe you want course of this year only?).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to incorporate the `Department` table in your query as well and join on the `ID`s. Then, you can also select the department `name` as well.

Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT p.name, d.name, c.name
FROM Course c, Schedule s, Professor p, Department d
WHERE p.id = s.professor_id AND s.course_id = c.id AND d.id = c.department_id
ORDER BY p.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also use the information on the `Department` table

```sql
SELECT
    p.NAME,
    d.NAME,
    c.NAME 
FROM
    PROFESSOR p,
    DEPARTMENT d,
    COURSE c, 
    SCHEDULE s
WHERE 
    p.ID = s.PROFESSOR_ID AND 
    d.ID = c.DEPARTMENT_ID AND
    c.ID = s.COURSE_ID
ORDER BY p.NAME;
```